# Storing element from repeater for use again

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a list I'm using like a discussion board. There is a box next to each user with a colour in it and their initials, I want to basically show a colour at random in the box (from a list), but re-use the same colour if that person has come up already. I've got the boxes working with the colour coming up from random but I can't work out how to use an item from the repeater to work out if they should re-use the colour instead of show a new colour at random.

HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptThread" OnItemDataBound="rptThread_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>    
                <li class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <div class="foo hidden-xs" runat="server" id="divColour"><center> <span><asp:Label runat="server" id="lblInitials"></asp:Label></span> </center></div>
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <ul class="list-inline meta text-muted">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblDate"></asp:Label></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="#"><asp:Label runat="server" id="lblName"></asp:Label></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p><asp:Label runat="server" id="lblText"></asp:Label></p>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

ItemDataBound:

```
  DataRowView nRow = null;
  ActiveDirectory AD = new ActiveDirectory();
  GeneralFunctions G = new GeneralFunctions();
    ArrayList Colours = G.getColours();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int r = rnd.Next(Colours.Count);


    switch (e.Item.ItemType)
    {
        case ListItemType.Item:
        case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
            nRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblInitials")).Text = AD.getInitialsFromAD(nRow["ThreadPerson"].ToString());
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDate")).Text = nRow["ThreadDate"].ToString();
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = AD.getFullNameFromSID(nRow["ThreadPerson"].ToString());
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblText")).Text = nRow["ThreadText"].ToString();
            ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divColour")).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: " + (string)Colours[r]);
            break;
    }
```

The colours list is just:

```
public ArrayList getColours()
        {
            ArrayList Colours = new ArrayList();
            Colours.Add("#22447a");
            Colours.Add("#761e10");
            Colours.Add("#256908");
            Colours.Add("#422562");
            etc (redacted).....
            return Colours;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary cache of users to colors. While processing the ItemDataBound event, check to see if the user's color is in the cache, if it is use it, otherwise chose a color for them and stick it in the cache for next time.

```
//this should be declared and initialized at the Page level so it is available across all runs of the ItemDataBound
var userColorCache = new Dictionary<string, string>();

DataRowView nRow = null;
ActiveDirectory AD = new ActiveDirectory();
GeneralFunctions G = new GeneralFunctions();
ArrayList Colours = G.getColours();
Random rnd = new Random();

switch (e.Item.ItemType)
{
    case ListItemType.Item:
    case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
        nRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        var personInitials = AD.getInitialsFromAD(nRow["ThreadPerson"].ToString());
        string userColor = null;
        if (userColorCache.ContainsKey(personInitials)) {
          userColor = userColorCache[personInitials];
        } else {
          int r = rnd.Next(Colours.Count);
          userColor = (string)Colours[r];
          userColorCache.Add(personInitials, userColor)
        }


        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblInitials")).Text = personInitials;
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDate")).Text = nRow["ThreadDate"].ToString();
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = AD.getFullNameFromSID(nRow["ThreadPerson"].ToString());
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblText")).Text = nRow["ThreadText"].ToString();
        ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divColour")).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: " + userColor);
        break;
}
```

Edit: to move cache logic for person below the assignment of the DataItem to local variable.

Comment: Thanks for that, but AD.getInitialsFromAD(nRow["ThreadPerson"].ToString()) - ThreadPerson isnt set at that point is it?

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was using the nRow variable. Just move the logic for that down inside the switch statement, or move the assignment of the nRow variable up in your ItemDataBound event.